# how to get multiple row with mysql IN statements

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Hi i have editid column as shown below. From these i want to get result row only as 3,0 and 3089,3,0 if i pass 3.
For eg:

```
SELECT * FROM `master_bom3` WHERE 3 IN(
`editid`
)
```

But am getting only one row as the result ie 3,0 only.

```
editid column
0
1,0
3087,0
3,0
3089,3,0
3081,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `master_bom3` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, `editid`)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hJY5WidAt6gJytkVGRNu37/0).
Results:

```
| editid   |
| -------- |
| 3,0      |
| 3089,3,0 |
```